# How to display comments as description paragraphs in Swagger in an ASP.NET Core API

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger

I have a web api in asp.net-core and I wanted to know how to put paragraphs as descriptions on the end points? I tried 
 
 \n \n , nothing works. I am putting the description in the "remarks" xml.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you must [configure Swashbuckle to use the documentation XML](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore#include-descriptions-from-xml-comments).

Then, use [`<summary>` and `<remarks>` tags](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/blob/95cb4d370e08e54eb04cf14e7e6388ca974a686e/test/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.Test/Fixtures/FakeControllerWithXmlComments.cs#L12-L17) for operation summary and description.

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Summary for ActionWithSummaryAndRemarksTags
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>
/// Remarks for ActionWithSummaryAndRemarksTags
/// </remarks>
public ActionResult ActionWithSummaryAndRemarksTags()
```

You can use Markdown to construct more complex documents:

````cs
/// <summary>
/// This is a short summary
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>
/// ## Usage
/// ...
/// ```
/// <![CDATA[
/// {
///   "html": "<h1>escape HTML with CDATA blocks</h1><img src=\"https://unsplash.it/400/200\" />"
/// }
/// ]]>
/// ```
///
/// ### A title
/// A paragrapth with [a link](https://example.com).
/// 
/// ```html
/// <h1>hello world, this is a code block</h1>
/// <img src="data:image/jpg,base64;..." />
/// ```
/// This is an inline code `https://unsplash.it/200/100`.
///
/// This is a separate paragraph
/// </remarks>
````

Comment: thanks, but I meant how can i make a new line in the "remarks" portion , what you wrote as "description". If I put <br > it just shows "<br >".

Comment: Use Markdown. See: https://github.com/abdusco/matbaa/blob/595e0d7ba7cdb89a4a473d953428d184af8fe426/src/AbdusCo.Matbaa/PdfController.cs#L27-L53

Comment: thanks, the indentation only goes to two levels? I am unable to have something like:
List1:
     -SubList1:
            -Sublist2:

Comment: @user2612665 Not sure, I'm sure Swashbuckle is using a proper markdown renderer, but .NET compiler might be messing up with the indentation